# PC to TV connection goes black when furnace or stove turns on

Tags: television

The pc is connected to TV via HDMI and it keeps going to a black screen when the furnace blower kicks on or off and also when the stove top oven is in use and making it clicking noises when its cooking food. It never does it when its just on the cable box or when using the PS4. It only happens when I am trying to use the TV as a second monitor. I tried different ports and different cables no change. Works just fine as long as nothing extra comes on. The furnace is in the hallway and stove is in the kitchen obviously. I doubt they would be on the same circuit and why would only one part of the TV be effected. The actual computer monitor has no issues with the flickering.

Comment: Does the TV flicker to a black screen? Does the picture come back? Is there power going to the TV when the stove or furnace blower kick on?

Comment: Sounds like some inductive kickback or voltage droop on the line for the tv if the PC monitor never fails in a similar fashion. A UPS for the tv would probably solve the problem a cheaper first try may be to switch legs the circuit breaker is on for the TV by moving the breaker up or down 1 position, swapping breakers if the panel is full and see if that cures the problem.

Comment: As a test, plug an extension cable into the same outlet, or a close outlet, to the TV, and run it to your PC and power the PC from the extension cable. If it no longer does it, either the TV or your Computer are on the same circuit as the other appliances. Also check the grounding on the outlets for the tv and the computer.

Comment: The picture comes right back it just happens when you hearing the blower kick in or today when the oven was warming it would click and the picture goes black for a split second. TV is on the whole time just lose the picture or display.  I just don't understand why it only effected with pc to TV nothing else hooked to the TV has this problem at anytime.

Comment: It doesn't really flicker. Tt just flips to black like nothing is hooked to it at all but doesn't turn off power. Its more like pulling the  hdmi cord out and plugging right back in.

Answer (score 3):

You said as a second monitor.

This typically happens when there is no signal to drive the monitor. Your PC is losing power via a "brown out" caused by a greater current draw. 
Is the TV plugged into the same outlet as the PC or a different outlet ?
Your HDMI connection -is it a cable or a HDMI transmitter , if it is a cable - How Long is the Cable ?

Measure the voltage in your PC's outlet, do the same for the TV (maybe you have a splitter - 6 way or something) make sure you measure with the components ON - that voltage should read above 108V [USA], if it is not your line voltage is low (check other outlets to be certain), the cause could be something in the home or something with the incoming power - the power company will need to boost your voltage via a tap if the latter is the case.

The reason the TV sees the problem and not the monitor - I am guessing you have a cable, the cable is probably 12 feet long, lots of resistance - lower signal level (voltage drop because of resistance). Furnace kicks on draws a heck of a lot of current (blow dryer on high might do the same), then your TV goes dark because the voltage dropped in the PC which was driving the HDMI across that cable, or your TV input for the HDMI dropped level or both, hence black flickering.

Get a 3 foot cable or an HDMI transmitter/receiver, that might tell you all you need to know - given the above explanation.

**EDIT 3/7/2017**

It is a voltage drop caused by the current requested by the furnace or oven. So that is the real culprit. It hi-lites the secondary issue you are facing one of your devices is unable to sustain proper regulation of power during the drop - I suspect the PC (a new PC power supply might be in order) - but it could as well be the TV, and it could also be that both have difficulty. Testing the AC line voltage level is the first thing I would do - if the voltage is 110 or lower - you might want to call an electrician or the power company and have that fixed. While 110 is acceptable - the furnace / oven kicking in drops that - and that reason alone it needs to be fixed (how is that done - the power company taps your transformer up a notch.)
In reality this dropping is bad for all of your electrical devices. 
Plug an **INCANDESCENT** lamp into the computer outlet or tv outlet does the light dim when the furnace or oven comes on ? [don't look at the light directly -just look to where you can notice if it gets dimmer for a split second, like a quick flicker. - Make sure it is an OLD SCHOOL INCANDESCENT not an LED or Compact Fluorescent].

Comment: It is a 12 foot cable DVI to HDMI.  I did have 2 6 foot ones with a link in the middle to join them. I thought that might be the issue so I went with a longer one piece cable. No change. They are not on the same outlet but it is on the same breaker. The other item are on a different breaker (oven, furnace blower) of course. The HDMI transmitter is a great idea.

Comment: 130FT (40M) HDMI 1.4 Repeater Extender Amplifier Booster Adapter 1080p 3D 4K*2K I was checking around I wonder is one of these might help.

Comment: @ChrisDawson it is possible for the repeater to be a help (and also possible not)  - are you able to use a Volt-Meter ? Measure the AC outlet voltage (or find a friend who knows how) check it at both the PC and the TV your voltage should be monitored with no furnace and also when the furnace kicks on - this will give you a big clue as to the problem. See edit. Commenting to long.